# Post Images Downsized via LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

Struggling with an issue around LinkedIn downsizing images posted via their API.  Hoping someone has some resources that might be able to assist?

When posting via LinkedIn's reach media share, as described here:

- https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/suggested/70781/image-specifications-for-your-linkedin-pages-and-career-pages?lang=en
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares

It seems their API only supports a "1.91:1 ratio" (1200 x 627)

What's ironic about this is 1.91:1 looks terrible in the application.

So after some experimentation (forgive the bright green background, I was testing whether white padding was being added) I discovered that LinkedIn's native posting of images is actually a 1.5375:1 ratio when done within the application, which lo and behold... actually looks good within the application.  Example:

[image: Image Example #1: Natively Posted Image]

So then naturally I try to post 1.5375 via the API and get these hideous gray bars on both sides:

[image: Image Example #2: API Posted Image]

Further, the API adds a crop factor to the overall height that is just simply not present when an image is added in the application natively.  This example is a side-by-side of the **exact same image**... (left = posted via API) (right = posted natively on LinkedIn)

[image: Image Example #3: Side by Side Comparison]

You can see how much better the native image looks.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Many thanks!!

Comment: can you wrap the images in html to change the height and width?

Comment: @aaronlilly I appreciate the suggestion, but no LinkedIn doesn't allow one to submit any raw HTML via their API.  I suspect this is a bug within LinkedIn's own platform, and posted this article in the hopes they see the in-congruency issues with their API and their native application, and correspondingly fix them.

Comment: though im not sure what set up you have, i was thinking you were retrieving the results of an api call and then possibly appending them, if this was the case maybe you could in the append wrap it with html to affect the display on your site.

Comment: @aaronlilly  Got it.  To clarify, this is not my site.  This is LinkedIn's site, and this is a POST of my image content via their API and a re-rendering of that content within their site.